# Convert string to dataframe, separated by colon

Tags: python, pandas

I have a string that comes from an article with a few hundred sentences. I want to convert the string to a dataframe, with each sentence as a row. For example,

```
data = 'This is a book, to which I found exciting. I bought it for my cousin. He likes it.'
```

I hope it becomes:

```
This is a book, to which I found exciting.
I bought it for my cousin.
He likes it.
```

As a python newbie, this is what I tried:

```
import pandas as pd
data_csv = StringIO(data)
data_df = pd.read_csv(data_csv, sep = ".")
```

With the code above, all sentences become column names. I actually want them in rows of a single column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `read_csv`. Just split by `'.'` and use the standard `pd.DataFrame`:

```
data = 'This is a book, to which I found exciting. I bought it for my cousin. He likes it.'
data_df = pd.DataFrame([sentence for sentence in data.split('.') if sentence],
                       columns=['sentences'])
print(data_df)

#                                     sentences
#  0  This is a book, to which I found exciting
#  1                  I bought it for my cousin
#  2                                He likes it
```

Keep in mind that this will break if there will be 
floating point numbers in some of the sentences. In this case you will need to change the format of your string (eg use `'\n'` instead of `'.'` to separate sentences.)

Comment: Don't forget to add back the full stop :)

Comment: Works, but will into problems with more complex input.

Comment: @cdwoelk more complex how? `'.'` in the middle of a sentence? floating points numbers? Then that becomes nltk question, not pandas.

Comment: @DeepSpace True. I'd probably lean towards using nltk for this. However, the quick and dirty solution works probably fine most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

this is a quick solution but it solves your issue:

```
data_df = pd.read_csv(data, sep=".", header=None).T
```

Comment: @DeepSpace solution is much better than this.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this via a list comprehension:

```
data = 'This is a book, to which I found exciting. I bought it for my cousin. He likes it.'

df = pd.DataFrame({'sentence': [i+'.' for i in data.split('. ')]})

print(df)

#                                      sentence
# 0  This is a book, to which I found exciting.
# 1                  I bought it for my cousin.
# 2                                He likes it.
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is called tokenizing sentences. The easiest way would be to use a Text-Mining library such as NLTK for it:

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
pd.DataFrame(sent_tokenize(data))
```

Otherwise you could simply try something like:

```
pd.DataFrame(data.split('. '))
```

However, this will fail if you run into sentences like this:

```
problem = 'Tim likes to jump... but not always!'
```